# How do I convert an object from an ArrayList() or ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<Integer>?

Tags: java, arraylist

So, in my code, I read in the .txt file to a single, unspecified ArrayList, but it is not converting back to an int or Integer when I try to parse it back out.
The text file looks like this:
*Name 1*
*Number 1*
*Number 2*
*Number 3*
*Name 2*
*etc.*
I am trying to make Number 1 increment up when Name 1 is selected from a list.
students is the initial ArrayList (tried both ArrayList and ArrayList())
kb is Scanner
players is ArrayList
totalgames is ArrayList that tries to rewrite students(k+1)

```
System.out.println(students.get(k));  
if(kb.nextInt()!=0)  
{  
players.add(k);  
totalgames.add((Integer)students.get(k+1));  
}
```

But it comes up with an incompatible types error.  Is there a way to make this error go away without completely changing all the ArrayLists?

Comment: Can you explain in a better manner?

Comment: Is there a separator between Number 3 and Name 2? Or is the first non-number line the next name? I would suggest using a different data-structure, but I'm not sure what you **want**... are you trying to sum `Number`(s) `1,2,3`?

Comment: Heard of autoboxing?...If there is an integer in the list, when you assign that particular element to `int` variable, it automatically gets type casted to integer.

Comment: @MathewsMathai I tried that.  It threw the same error.  What I am trying to do is increase Number 1 by a pre-determined amount (1) each time Name 1 is called.  And Elliot, my program goes name 1/break/.../number 3/break/name 2/break/...

Comment: can you share the complete code?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback (namely the prompting for a more specific question), but I figured it out.  I'm just changing how students is written into, and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList students=new ArrayList();
        int num=0;
        while (qbrdr.hasNext()&&num<loop)
        {
            students.add(qbrdr.nextLine());
            students.add(new Integer(qbrdr.nextInt()));
            students.add(new Double(qbrdr.nextDouble()));
            students.add(new Double(qbrdr.nextDouble()));
            num+=4;
        }
```

During the initialization, I just needed it to record them as int or double not Object or String.